# Get html source from internet meet some issue

Tags: c#

I want to fetch a web page to analyze stock information. I use the following sample code to get html data using c#. While it compiles, running it always ends in an error.

[image]

The following is my sample code:

```
string urlAddress = "http://pchome.syspower.com.tw/stock/sto0/ock2/sid2404.html";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = 1414;
var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("is_check=1"), 0, 10);
requestStream.Close();
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string rawData = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
response.Close();
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Could it be, that the URL you're posting to doesn't expect post requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors were mostly related to the order of your code and the closing of `Stream` objects your were still going to use.

Also I recommend to use `using` where possible to correctly dispose objects.

Use this code:

```
string rawData;
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("is_check=1");

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            rawData = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it not work, the code get stuck under using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) :(

Comment: Sorry to say, but it works fine here. What is the error message?

Comment: @user1328842: Check the actual message. Click `Break` and see what the error dialog says.

Comment: I have added the pic in topic, do you see the new picture?

Comment: @user1328842: yes, but it doesn't help. Click `Break` in that dialog and see if you can get additional information from the exception. Are you sure you can reach the url from a browser?

Comment: yep, the url can reach, i have added the click break image

Comment: @user1328842: Strange. It makes no sense. Here the code works. Can you try to create a new project from scratch and only use the code in my post?

Comment: Hi, Patrick, I have created a new project, and it shows the same error...I'll upload my test project...

Comment: Hi, Patrick, it work! I restart my pc, and it could get stock data, i really thanks for your help ^^

Comment: Wonderful. Good luck with it.